# BASH get value from string

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have this string stored in a variable

```
<li class="rainbow-list-item southern disrupted " data-line-id="lul-southern" data-severity-codes="4,6,9" data-mode="national-rail">
```

and I would like to take only the numerical values for data-severity-codes. Take in mind that:

1. The numerical values are 1,2 or 3 characters
2. The data-line-id length change

Comment: [Obligatory link.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/3960947#1732454)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
$ MYVAR='<li class="rainbow-list-item southern disrupted " data-line-id="lul-southern" data-severity-codes="4,6,9" data-mode="national-rail">'
$ echo $MYVAR | tr ' ' '\n' | awk -F= '/data-severity-codes/ {print $2}'
"4,6,9"
```

You can also use sed to remove " and replace , by a blank if you need it:

```
$ echo $MYVAR | tr ' ' '\n' | awk -F= '/data-severity-codes/ {print $2}' | sed -e 's/"//g' -e 's/,/ /g'
4 6 9
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the matching operator `=~`:

```
#! /bin/bash
var='<li class="rainbow-list-item southern disrupted " data-line-id="lul-southern" data-severity-codes="4,6,9" data-mode="national-rail">'

if [[ $var =~ data-severity-codes=\"([^\"]+)\" ]] ; then
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
fi
```

Output:

4,6,9

Or use an XML-aware tool:

```
xmllint --xpath li/@data-severity-codes - <<< "$var</li>" \
| cut -f2 -d\"
```